# JSF ViewScoped bean not instantiating

Tags: primefaces, java-8, jsf-2.2, tomcat8, managed-bean

I have a view scoped jsf managed bean which is not instantiated when I add a method to it. This bean uses a session scoped bean and try to access data from it.

Sample code.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DecodingBean implements Serializable {

private Charge charge;

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{configBean}")
private ConfigBean configBean;

public void setConfigBean(ConfigBean configBean) {
    this.configBean = configBean;
}

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    charge = new Charge();
}

public void save() {
    try (DbConnection dbConnection = DbUtil.getDbConnection();
            MyDao1 myDao1= new  MyDao1 (dbConnection );
            MyDao2 myDao2= new MyDao2 (dbConnection )) {
        charge.setPId(selectedPId);
        charge.setSId(selectedSId);
        charge.setStatusId(configBean.getNewStatusId());
        myDao2.updateCharge(charge);
        myDao1.deleteModifier(charge.getId(), ModifierType.P.toString());
        insertChargeModifiers(charge, myDao1);
        charge = new Charge();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("Error saving Charge", ex);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error occurred while saving, please try again", ""));
    }
}
```

If I remove the save method the bean is instantiated.

Comment: Do you see any error message? Check you logs to see if you are getting a ClassNotFoundException if some of your classes are in another project and are not added to Deployment assembly of the War.

Comment: @Ravi is right.... debug...

Answer (score 0):

This issue is gone after correcting version of jsf library.
I had jar for 2.2.7 and web-facesconfig for different version.

Still not sure this was the reason but it is gone.

Comment: So what version do you use now? 4.3.1? And which implementation?

Comment: JSF 2.2.0 and primefaces 6.2.3

Comment: So you went from 2.2.7 to 2.2.0 for a fix? Weird.... I'd go to 2.2.14 then